# using a loop in R to output many files

Tags: r, loops

My goal it to run all the files in a folder called "myname.output/" through a loop function to generate multiple CSV files each being myname1, myname2 .... etc

This is what i have so far

```
 sample_d <- list.dirs("myname.output/", recursive = F)


batch_process_samples <- function (sample_d) {
for (file in list.dirs("sample_d", full.names = T)) {    
    writef <- process_s(file)
    write.csv(writef "myname.csv") 
}
}
```

Where process_s is a function in a different file.

However it does not work...
I am pretty sure i can use sprintf to create unique file names but I'm not exactly sure how,
Thanks!

Just more info: if i run it an assign to to a variable, the function works just the variable comes out empty, but no R errors.

Comment: Also, I assume it's just a typo when you wrote your question, but you're missing a comma in the write.csv line.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear to me, but it sounds like you are having trouble getting a unique output file name for each iteration. You can use the `basename` function to remove the relative path from the input file in each iteration and then just paste a new prefix like this:

```
write.csv(writef, file=paste("processed_",basename(file),sep=''))
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will guide you forward.

Problem #1 is that the first argument in list.dirs() was a hard-coded string **"sample_d"** rather than the variable **sample_d**

Problem #2 is that **process_s**  is probably some function which I do not have and so cannot help directly.  So I created a toy processing example by appending the filename with "XX"

```
sample_d <- list.dirs("myname.output/", recursive = F)

batch_process_samples <- function (sample_d) {
    for (file in list.dirs(sample_d, full.names = T)) { # <== Problem #1 here   
    writef <- paste0(file, "XX")                   #   <== Problem #2 here 
  print(writef)                                    #   <== results out 
    }
}

batch_process_samples(sample_d)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create unique file names using paste. This worked for me:

```
sample_d <- list.files("myname.output/", recursive=F)

i <- 0
batch_process_samples <- function(file_list) {
  for(file in file_list) { 
    i++
    writef <- data.frame(read.csv(file))
    write.csv(writef, file = paste0("myname",i,".csv"))
  }
}

batch_process_samples(sample_d)
```

If you're reading files, you'll want `list.files()` instead of `list.dirs()`.